# calculating matrix gradient

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Can someone help me understand why $\hat\alpha$ is the average of all $y$ values? I'm not exactly sure how to take the derivative of the $J$ matrix such that when I set the gradient with respect to $\alpha$ to $0$, I get the stated result.

[image]

**Also, if we shuffle the rows of $X$ and $Y$ and calculate $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$, are we going to get the same answer?**

Comment: You can differentiate it with the product rule. Let $r(\alpha)$ be the residual considered as a function of $\alpha$. Then $\frac{d}{d\alpha} r^T r = \frac{dr}{d\alpha}^T r + r^T\frac{dr}{d\alpha} = 2 \frac{dr}{d\alpha}^T r$. And then note that $\frac{dr}{d\alpha} = \mathbf{1}$

Comment: Where you wrote about "the rows of $X$ and $Y$", did you mean $\mathbf y$ rather than $Y$? $\qquad$

Comment: I meant big X and big Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $J(w,\alpha) = \|Xw + \alpha\mathbf{1}-y\|^2 + \lambda\|w\|^2$. Noting that the derivative of $\|x\|^2$ is $2x^T$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial\alpha} = 2(Xw+\alpha\mathbb 1 - y)^T\mathbb 1 = w^TX^T\mathbf 1 + n\alpha-y^T\mathbf 1.
$$
Since $y^T\mathbf 1 = n\overline{y}$ and $X^T\mathbf 1 = n\overline{x} = 0$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial\alpha} = n(\alpha-\overline y).
$$
Deriving with respect to $w$ gives
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial w} = 2(Xw + \alpha\mathbb 1 - y)^TX + 2\lambda w^T.
$$
Now, $\mathbb 1^TX = (X^T\mathbf 1)^T = 0$, so
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial w} = 2(Xw - y)^TX + 2\lambda w^T.
$$
I am sure you can do the rest alone. ;-)